# prevent div's from taking 100% width

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">

  <div style="
         border: 2px solid black;
         margin: 0 auto;
         text-align: center;
         padding: 3px;">

    Hello<br />Hola

  </div>

  <div style="
         border: 2px solid black;
         margin: 0 auto;
         text-align: center;
         padding: 3px;">

    Another Sentence

  </div>

</div>
```

I have a problem: the borders of the inner div's reach over the whole width of the page, but i want them to only frame the content inside them. If i use: `display: inline` the borders frame each line separately and overlap, so that doesn't work - can somebody help?

P.S the style's aren't declared like this in the original document but in a stylesheet

Comment: display: inline-block, thanks to meder and Nikita Rybak

Comment: Amazing how hard it was to find the correct search term to find this.  Thanks, 12 years later! :)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Assign a width to the absolutely positioned element? If you're looking for shrink-wrapping, `float:left` or `display:inline-block` are perfect for that.

Comment: This also affects the margin collapsing top and bottom.

Comment: Nowadays there's `width: fit-content`.

Comment: @leymannx - it's an entirely different world nowadays compared to the limitations we had back then :)

Answer (score 25):

Try `display:inline-block`, it always helps me in situations like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/FaYLk/

Answer (score 10):

Its not as simple to just do:

```
display: inline-block;
```

You must do more than that to cross browser this.

```
display: inline-block;
display: -moz-inline-stack; /* for firefox 2 */
*display: inline; /* for ie 6 and 7 */
```

Answer (score 4):

Put a container around all the content. E.g

```
<div class='container'> <div>I wont be 100%</div> <div>Nor will I :)</div> </div>
.container{ display: inline-block; }
```